# show output from python-shell-send-region

Tags: python, ipython

Using `python.el` and `ipython.exe` (from Miniconda3), I'd like to highlight a portion of code and execute it in the associated inferior python buffer. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

myvar = 100+200
        ^^^^^^^ (this is my selected region)
```

If I use `C-c C-c`, it correctly sources the file. That's not what I want.

If I highlight the region as depicted above and use `C-c C-r` (`python-shell-send-region`), the entire line is executed, not just the region. That is, `myvar` should not be defined by this step. I'd like to send *just* the highlight region.

So I created an edited version of `python-shell-buffer-substring`, omitting the part that redefines `start`:

```
  (let* ((start (save-excursion
                  ;; Normalize start to the line beginning position.
                  (goto-char start)
                  (line-beginning-position)))
```

I also create `my-python-shell-send-region`, where the only difference is it calls `my-python-shell-buffer-substring`. This properly creates the substring

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

100+200
```

and sends it correctly to the inferior process. Except ... the output is inhibited (generally a good thing), and I'd like to see the output `300`. I see the function `python-shell-send-string-no-output`, but I don't see a way to allow output when using `*-send-string`.

**Q:** how to allow the output, and/or is there a better mechanism for doing this?

(In the unrelated package `ess`, I use `C-u C-c C-r` for show-no-output, and `C-c C-r` when I want the output shown. I can deal with a reversal of this logic, that's not the issue for this question.)

(`emacs-25.2.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)` and `ein-20171128.516`)

***EDIT***

After some more digging (thanks wvxvw), I found that removing the inserted `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line from the pasted string allowed the inferior process to print the output, but only on single-line regions. For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

myvar = 100+200
200+300
```

Highlighting just `100+200` produced the output `300`, good. Highlighting from `100` through `300` on the next line, however, produced no output. If the highlighted string is on a single line and contains semicolon-delimited commands (e.g., `100+200;200+300`), then the output from the last command is shown, nothing else (which is, I believe, correct behavior for python.) So the problem remains with multi-line regions.

Comment: The best I can think of so far is if you add your function to the list `comint-output-filter-functions`, then it will be called with the output that would be sent to the comint buffer, our you could entirely bypass `comint` and get hold of the process associated with the buffer, temporarily modify its `filter-output-function` to collect the results, and then restore it to the previous state.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Though I couldn't get it to work, it did cause me to find a culprit ... whether it is the best/only solution is tbd.