# Elpy shell-send-region to a particular named Python buffer

Tags: elpy

I often open up interactive python sessions particular to the project that I'm working on, and will use `M-x rename-buffer` to title them `*Python[Project1]*`, *Python[Project2]*`, etc.

I would like to configure my `C-c C-c` to send to the correct project's buffer.

I know I can use `python-shell-buffer-name . "Python[Project1]")` to set a buffer's name, but what variable do I set to ensure that `C-c C-c` and similar will respect this, versus sending to `*Python*` or to the last used buffer, which may be `*Python[project_wrong]*` ?

I've looked at the following:

- [show output from python-shell-send-region](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37159/show-output-from-python-shell-send-region)

Answer (score 1):

One way to set temporarily `python-shell-buffer-name` during a function call is to
call this function inside a `let` statement that sets `python-shell-buffer-name`.

```
(defun adl/elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer ()
  "Send python- region or buffer to *Python[ PY-BUFFER ]*."
  (interactive)
  (let ((python-shell-buffer-name (concat "Python[" (file-name-base (buffer-name)) "]")))
    (elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer)))
```

Using the function above instead of `(elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer)`, you will
send the code of `file.py` to a buffer named `*Python[file]*`.

Code from different files with the same name will run in the same buffer.

If you change `(file-name-base (buffer-name))` to `default-directory`, all files from
the same directory will run in the same buffer named `*Python[path/to/directory/]*`.

If you change `(file-name-base (buffer-name))` to `(buffer-file-name)`, each file
will run in a different buffer named `*Python[path/to/directory/file.py]*`. Note that
unsaved buffers, e.g., `*scratch*`, will run in `*Python[]*`.

If none of the above satisfies you, choose a better string :).

You can replace `"C-c C-c"` key binding to the new function (or use other binding):

```
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") #'adl/elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer)))
```